# Polyglossia and German guillemets

Tags: polyglossia

I am using `polyglossia` and I try to make the input of the German `guillemets` a little easier. But my definition in the following `TeX-file` is not working: Th first case gives `»Text«` in the second case I get `">Text"<` .

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[parskip = full]{scrartcl}
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[babelshorthands=true]{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes} % \enquote{}
\newcommand{\myquote}[1]{">#1"<}
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\verb!">Text"<! gives ">Text"< . % ok

\verb!\myquote{Text}! gives \myquote{Text}. % wrong

\verb!\enquote{Text}! gives \enquote{Text}. % ok 

\end{document}
```

I could use the `csquote`-package with `\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}` and `\enquote{Text}` as above. But why mixing up?

Comment: well I would use csquotes, but if you want your own command: move the definition  behind \begin{document} as shorthands are not active in the preamble.

Comment: @Ulrike Life is learning. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `"` to be active in order that the definition works.

```
\documentclass[parskip = full]{scrartcl}
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[babelshorthands=true]{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes} % \enquote{}

\catcode`"=\active
\newcommand{\myquote}[1]{">#1"<}
\catcode`"=12
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\verb!">Text"<! gives ">Text"<. % ok

\verb!\myquote{Text}! gives \myquote{Text}. % wrong

\verb!\enquote{Text}! gives \enquote{Text}. % ok

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, without explicitly setting catcodes,

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`" \lowercase{\endgroup
  \newcommand{\myquote}[1]{~>#1~<}%
}
```

But, of course,

```
\newcommand{\myquote}[1]{»#1«}
```

is easier.